# Disable Serial Console on an Android Emulator

Tags: flutter, android-emulator, virtual-device-manager

I've been learning and working with Flutter for a few weeks now. I used some of the Android Emulators that Android Studio provides and it was doing fine.
But recently, I opened an emulator to run a Flutter project while a memory card was connected with my laptop, and suddenly a notification was shown in the emulator of detecting a SD card and with that another notification was shown saying:

```
Serial console enabled 
Performance is impacted. To disable, check bootloader
```

The notification is not clickable, and neither it removes even after I deleted all the emulators that I installed using the AVD manager. And as the notification says, it really is impacting the performance of the emulators. Before it showed up, I could see the changes in the app immediately after making changes to the code and saving it, but now, it takes so much time to show the changes even if I use **hot reload** or **hot restart**.

Is there any way to get rid of this? How can I disable the Serial console?

Answer (score 0):

Enter engineer mode (*#801#) and disable the option that says serial. Google it how to access engineer mode if the code doesn't work for you.